# How to change html input type based on another text box value MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I went through similar questions but still unable to figure out.

I have a form as shown below. One of the input type is a hidden. The values for both textboxes are specified by the model passed from the controller.

```
 <form asp-action="Edit">
     //input one
     <div class="form-group" id="control1">
            <label asp-for="Value" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" required="required" id="param2" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger"></span>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" asp-for="Type" id="param1" />
 </form>
```

The default input type is textbox, but suppose if the value of **asp-for="Type"** is equal to "drop", I want to change the input type to dropdown list with True or False Option. I have tried the following. I added the new form group and assigned id=control2.

```
       <div class="form-group" id="control2">
            <select asp-for="Value">
                <option value="True">True</option>
                <option value="False">False</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

What I did was that, I select the value of **param1** using jquery and if it is equal to "bool" then I **hide control1** and **show control2** (which is wrong). So even though I have selected the value using the dropdownlist from control 2, the textbox value from control1 (which I hide) is being used when POST occurred.

Can someone please advise me on this? Either an alternative method or continue using my method by to use the value of **control2**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I read your question multiple times but can't figure out what you mean. Could you post your jQuery to show what you have done / try to do?

Comment: may I check which part you are not clear. if the condition is met, want to use enable the dropdown list. that is what I want in short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery you can use the `razor` syntax to add or remove the element from DOM. Update your code as below.

```html
<form asp-action="Edit">
     //input one
  
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Type" id="param1" />
  @if(Model.Type.Equals("Drop"))
  {
   <div class="form-group" id="control2">
            <select asp-for="Value">
                <option value="True">True</option>
                <option value="False">False</option>
            </select>
  </div>
  }
  else
  {
  <div class="form-group" id="control1">
            <label asp-for="Value" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" required="required" id="param2" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  }
     
 </form>
```

Here if condition is true it will add drop down in DOM else it will append texbox.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Abishek. This works like a charm. Thank you very much - have a good day!